# Salvar Registro de campo texto desabilitado AJAX + PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Amigos, bom dia!

Tenho um formulário em php onde tenho que realizar manutenções, porém não foi eu quem desenvolveu, o antigo analista não está mais na empresa.

Neste formulário, existe um campo onde a pessoa digita um código localizador(empresa), e tem um campo ao lado que está desabilitado, onde trás o nome da empresa.
Nos registros do formulário, fica salvo apenas o código localizador, e surgiu a necessidade de salvar em uma coluna ao lado, o nome da empresa também.
Porém, não estou conseguindo fazer com que o insert do SQL salve essa informação no registro, quando salva, a coluna que deveria trazer o nome, vem com o campo em branco.

Nos códigos do PHP, os campos relacionados ao código estão referenciados como **"OAC"** e o nome do OAC é a parte onde não consigo fazer com que fique salvo no registro.

Abaixo o código do index PHP do formulário:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Augusta | Classificador E-LATAM</title>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE'/>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>

    <!-- CSS -->
        <!-- bootStrap -->
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo RAIZ ?>/css/bootstrap.css'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo RAIZ ?>/css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
    <!-- jQuery --> 
        <script src='<?php echo RAIZ_augusta ?>icc/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>    
        <!-- bootStrap -->
        <script src='<?php echo RAIZ ?>/js/bootstrap.js'></script>
    <!--[if IE]>
        <script src='<?php echo RAIZ_augusta ?>icc/js/html5.js'></script>
        <link href='<?php echo RAIZ ?>/css/bootstrap-ie7.css' rel='stylesheet'>
        <script src="<?php echo RAIZ ?>/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php echo RAIZ ?>/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='all' href='<?php echo RAIZ_augusta ?>icc/css/icc_ie8.css'/>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 7]>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='all' href='<?php echo RAIZ_augusta ?>icc/css/ie.css'/>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo RAIZ_augusta ?>icc/js/IE8.js'></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='all' href='<?php echo RAIZ_augusta ?>icc/css/ie6.css'/>
    <![endif]-->

    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function(){
            carregar_form(); 
        });
    </script>
    <script> <!-- carregar form -->
        function carregar_form() {
            if( true ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "classificador_Nucleo_ajax.php", 
                    dataType: "html",
                    type: "POST", 
                    data: { 
                        'seccion': 'carregarForm'   
                    }
                    ,beforeSend: function(){
                        $("#form_classificador").html("<div class='row text-center' style='margin-top:15px;'><img src='http://57.228.131.75/augusta/img/miniload.gif' alt='Carregando'/><div>"); 
                    }
                    ,success: function( data ) {
                        $("#form_classificador").html( data ); 
                        document.getElementById('filtro_Setor').value = "";
                        document.getElementById('filtro_Tipo').value = "";
                    }
                })
            }           
        }
    </script>
    <script> <!-- carrega sutipo -->
        function carregarSubtipo() {
            if( true ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "classificador_Nucleo_ajax.php", 
                    dataType: "html",
                    type: "POST", 
                    data: { 
                        'seccion': 'carregarSubtipo',
                        'tipo'  : $('#filtro_Tipo').val()
                    }
                    ,beforeSend: function(){
                        $("#div_subtipo").html("<div class='row text-center' style=''><img style='height:36px;' src='http://57.228.131.75/augusta/img/loadbar.gif'/><div>"); 
                    }
                    ,success: function( data ) {
                        $("#div_subtipo").html( data ); 
                        document.getElementById('filtro_Subtipo').value = "";
                    }
                })
            }           
        }
        function carregarOAC() {
            if( true ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "classificador_Nucleo_ajax.php", 
                    dataType: "html",
                    type: "POST", 
                    data: { 
                        'seccion': 'carregarOAC',
                        'oac'   : $('#filtro_OAC').val()
                    }
                    ,beforeSend: function(){
                        $("#div_OAC_nome").html("<div class='row text-center' style=''><img style='height:36px;''src='http://57.228.131.75/augusta/img/loadbar.gif'/><div>"); 
                    }
                    ,success: function( data ) {
                        $("#div_OAC_nome").html( data ); 
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script> <!-- function guardar e limpar -->
        function guardar(){
            if (  $( "#filtro_Setor" ).val() == null){
                alert("Por favor, informe o Setor");
                $("#filtro_Atendimento").focus();
                return false;
            }
            if (  $( "#filtro_Tipo" ).val() == null){
                alert("Por favor, informe o tipo da ligação");
                $("#filtro_Tipo").focus();
                return false;
            }
            if (  $( "#filtro_Subtipo" ).val() == null){
                alert("Por favor, informe o subtipo da ligação");
                $("#filtro_Subtipo").focus();
                return false;
            }
            if (  $( "#filtro_OAC" ).val() == null){
                alert("Por favor, informe o código OAC");
                $("#filtro_OAC").focus();
                return false;
            }
            var valor  = document.getElementById("filtro_OAC").value;
            if (valor.length != 5) {
                alert("Por favor, informe um código OAC válido");
                $("#filtro_OAC").focus();
                return false;
            }
            if(true) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "classificador_Nucleo_ajax.php", 
                    dataType: "html",
                    type: "POST", 
                    data: { 
                        'seccion'   : 'guardar',
                        'Setor'     : $( "#filtro_Setor").val(),
                        'tipo'              : $( "#filtro_Tipo" ).val(),
                        'subtipo'           : $( "#filtro_Subtipo").val(),
                        'oac'   : $( "#filtro_OAC").val()
                    } 
                    ,beforeSend: function(){
                        $("#retorno").html("<div class='row text-center' style='margin-top:15px;'><img src='http://57.228.131.75/augusta/img/miniload.gif' alt='Carregando'/><div>"); 
                    }
                    ,success: function( data ) {
                        $( "#retorno" ).html( data ); 
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        function limpar(){
            carregar_form();
        };
    </script>
    <style>
        .titulo {
            font-size: 24px;
            color: #0054bf; 
            display: block;
            border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(163, 163, 163, 0.3);
            margin-bottom: 15px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!--[if IE]><?php imprimeMenuHeaderAugustaIE('Nucleo', 'Classif', @$_SESSION[ "bp" ])?><![endif]-->
    <!--[if ! IE]><!--><?php imprimeMenuHeaderAugusta('Nucleo', 'Classif', @$_SESSION[ "bp" ]) ?><!--<![endif]-->

    <section id="content">
        <section id="main"> 
            <div id="form_classificador"></div>
        </section>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Abaixo o código da parte AJAX do php:

```
 <?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
    include 'classificador_Nucleo_sql.php';
    if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}

    $seccion = $_POST["seccion"];
    @$setor = $_POST['Setor'];
    @$tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
    @$subtipo = $_POST['subtipo'];
    @$oac = $_POST['oac'];

    if($seccion == "carregarForm"){ carregarForm();}
    if($seccion == "carregarSubtipo"){ carregarSubtipo($tipo);}
    if($seccion == "guardar"){ guardar($setor, $tipo, $subtipo, $oac);}
    if($seccion == "carregarOAC"){ carregarOAC($oac);}

function carregarForm(){

    $tipos = obtiene_filtros('tipo', null);
    $filtro_Setor = obtiene_Setor();

    $out = '<div class="panel panel-default col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2" style="padding:0px;">
                <div class="panel-body" id="bodyForm">
                    <form class="form-horizontal">';
                        $out.='<fieldset>
                            <legend>Classificador E-LATAM</legend>';
                            if(true){ //NomeOperador
                                $out.='<div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="filtro_NomeOperador" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label">Usuário</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7" style="padding-left:0px;">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filtro_Nome" disabled value="'.$_SESSION['nomeGuerra'].'">
                                    </div>
                                </div>';
                            }
                            if(true){//Setor(Tipo Ligação)
                            $out.='<fieldset>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="filtro_Setor" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label">Tipo Ligação</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="padding-left:0px;">
                                        <select class="form-control" id="filtro_Setor">';
                                            foreach ($filtro_Setor as $a){
                                                $out.='<option value="'.utf8_decode($a['setor']).'">'.utf8_decode($a['setor']).'</option>';
                                            }
                                        $out.='</select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </fieldset>';
                            }
                            if(true){//tipo
                                $out.='<div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label" for="filtro_Tipo">Motivo</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" style="padding-left:0px;">
                                        <select class="form-control" id="filtro_Tipo" onchange="carregarSubtipo();">';
                                            foreach ($tipos as $v){
                                                $out.='<option value="'.utf8_decode($v['valor']).'">'.utf8_decode($v['valor']).'</option>';
                                            }
                                        $out.='</select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>';
                            }
                            if(true){ //subtipo
                                $out.='<div class="form-group" id="div_subtipo">
                                    <label class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label" for="filtro_Subtipo">Submotivo</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" style="padding-left:0px;">
                                        <select class="form-control" id="filtro_Subtipo"></select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>';
                            }
                            if(true){ //OAC
                                $out.='<div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label" for="filtro_OAC">OAC</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" style="padding-left:0px;">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filtro_OAC" >
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" style="padding-left:0px;" id="div_OAC_nome">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filtro_OAC_nome" disabled >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group hidden" id="div_alertOAC">
                                    <label class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label"></label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-9 alert-sm alert-danger">
                                        O OAC deve ser um código de 5 digitos.
                                    </div>
                                </div>';
                            }
                        $out.='</fieldset>';
                        if(true){ //botões
                            $out.='<fieldset style="margin-top: 15px;" id="retorno">
                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2">
                                    <div class="btn btn-sm btn-default" onclick="limpar()"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-close"></i>&nbsp;Cancelar</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-1">
                                    <div class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="guardar()"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-save"></i>&nbsp;Salvar</div>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>';
                        }
                    $out.='</form>
                </div>
            </div>';

            /*Valida se o OAC tem 5 digitos*/
            if(true){
            $out.='<script>
                    filtro_OAC.onblur = function() {
                        var valor  = document.getElementById("filtro_OAC").value;
                        if (valor.length != 5) {
                            document.getElementById("div_alertOAC").classList.remove("hidden");
                        } else {
                            if (valor.length >= 1) {
                                document.getElementById("div_alertOAC").classList.add("hidden");
                                carregarOAC();
                            }
                        }
                    };
                </script>';
            }
echo $out;
}
function carregarSubtipo($tipo){

    $filtro_duvida = obtiene_filtros('subtipo',utf8_decode($tipo));

    $out = '<label class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 control-label" for="filtro_Subtipo">Subtipo</label>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" style="padding-left:0px;">
        <select class="form-control" id="filtro_Subtipo">';
            foreach ($filtro_duvida as $v){
                $out .= "<option value='".utf8_decode($v['valor'])."'>".utf8_decode($v['valor'])."</option>";
            }
        $out.='</select>
    </div>';
echo $out;
}
function guardar($setor, $tipo, $subtipo, $oac){
        if(guardarResposta(utf8_decode($setor),utf8_decode($tipo),utf8_decode($subtipo),utf8_decode($oac))){
            $out = '<div class="alert alert-success text-center col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                Dados salvos com sucesso.
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                <div class="btn btn-sm btn-default col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1" onclick="limpar()">
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-plus-square-o"></i>&nbsp;Novo
                </div>
            </div>';
        } else {
            $out = '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
                Erro ao Salvar! <br> Tente novamente em alguns segundos <br> caso o erro persista informe seu lider
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2">
                <div class="btn btn-sm btn-default" onclick="limpar()"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-plus-square-o"></i>&nbsp;Novo</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-3 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-1">
                <div class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="guardar()"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-save"></i>&nbsp;Salvar</div>
            </div>
            ';
        }

    echo $out;
}
function carregarOAC($oac){

        $nomeOAC = obtiene_OAC($oac);

        $out = '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="filtro_OAC_nome" disabled value="'.$nomeOAC.'" display="'.$nomeOAC.'">';


        echo $out;
}

?>
```

A última function carregarOAC($oac) é onde trás o campo desabilitado com o nome do código OAC...

E o código abaixo é referente a consulta SQL feita para salvar os registros na base SQL:

```
<?php 
    set_time_limit( 0 );
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
    include '..\..\complemento\sql_login.php';
    if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}

    function obtiene_Setor(){
        $conexion = conexion();
        $link_augusta = sqlsrv_connect( $conexion[ "idt_augusta" ][ "server" ], $conexion[ "idt_augusta" ][ "info" ] );

        $sql= "SELECT T.Setor AS Setor
            FROM ClassificadorNucleo_setor AS T";

        $resultado = sqlsrv_query( $link_augusta, $sql );
        while( $fila = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $resultado, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {
            $arreglo[] = array( 
                "setor"     => utf8_encode( $fila[ "Setor" ] ),
            );
        }

        sqlsrv_free_stmt( $resultado );
        sqlsrv_close( $link_augusta ); 
        return @$arreglo;

    }
    function obtiene_filtros ($filtro,$aux){
        $conexion = conexion();
        $link_augusta = sqlsrv_connect( $conexion[ "idt_augusta" ][ "server" ], $conexion[ "idt_augusta" ][ "info" ] );

        if($filtro=='tipo'){
            $sql = "SELECT A.TIPO AS valor
                FROM ClassificadorNucleo_motivos AS A
                GROUP BY A.TIPO ORDER BY A.TIPO";
        }
        if($filtro=='subtipo'){
            $sql = "SELECT A.SUBTIPO AS valor
            FROM ClassificadorNucleo_motivos AS A
            WHERE A.TIPO = '".$aux."'
            GROUP BY A.SUBTIPO
            ORDER BY A.SUBTIPO ";
        }

        $resultado = sqlsrv_query( $link_augusta, $sql );
        while( $fila = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $resultado, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {
            $arreglo[] = array( 
                "valor"     => utf8_encode( $fila[ "valor" ] ),
            );
        }

        sqlsrv_free_stmt( $resultado );
        sqlsrv_close( $link_augusta ); 
        return $arreglo;
    }   
    function guardarResposta($setor, $tipo, $subtipo, $oac){
        $conexion = conexion();
        $link_augusta = sqlsrv_connect( $conexion[ "idt_augusta" ][ "server" ], $conexion[ "idt_augusta" ][ "info" ] );

        $sql="INSERT INTO ClassificadorNucleo_registros (nome, chapa, lider, setor, tipo, subtipo, data, oac)
        SELECT '".$_SESSION['nomeGuerra']."', '".$_SESSION['chapa']."', contrato_resumido, '".$setor."', '".$tipo."', '".$subtipo."', '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."', '".$oac."'
        FROM usr_usuarios
        WHERE bp = '".$_SESSION['bp']."'";

        $arreglo = sqlsrv_query( $link_augusta, $sql );
        sqlsrv_close( $link_augusta ); 
        return $arreglo;
    }
    function obtiene_OAC($oac){
        $conexion = conexion();
        $link_augusta = sqlsrv_connect( $conexion[ "idt_augusta" ][ "server" ], $conexion[ "idt_augusta" ][ "info" ] );

        $sql= "SELECT T.NOME
            FROM ClassificadorNucleo_motivosOAC AS T
            WHERE T.OAC = '".$oac."'";

        $resultado = sqlsrv_query( $link_augusta, $sql );
        while( $fila = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $resultado, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {
            $arreglo =  utf8_encode( $fila[ "NOME" ] );
        }

        sqlsrv_free_stmt( $resultado );
        sqlsrv_close( $link_augusta ); 
        return @$arreglo;

    }
?>
```

Segue uma imagem de como é o formulário para que fique mais claro:

[image: XHTML válido]

Desde já agradeço pela ajuda de todos!

Answer (score 1):

Tenta trocar lá no Ajax de carregarOAC, em 'oac', o valor $("#filtro_OAC").val por $("#filtro_OAC_nome").val

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Ramones, mas infelizmente não resolveu.
Quando eu altero para $("#filtro_OAC_nome").val, e digito o código OAC, o campo bloqueado que trás o nome, fica vazio, não trás o nome.

Acredito que teria que fazer alguma function nova pra armazenar o nome e o código..
Mas ainda não encontrei uma maneira de fazer isso